# How to loop through Nested Json Array with (JavaScript) for loop and display the text

Tags: javascript, json, loops, nested-loops

This may be a fairly simple question but it's just not working for me no matter how many times I change the for loop around. So how would you loop through this array using a for loop in JavaScript?

```
var fielditems =[
     [["News Tips"],["Opinions"],["MedMinutes"]],
     [["Yes"],["No"],["Maybe"]],
     [["How"],["Why"],["When"]]
];
```

This is what I have and it's not working. I used an alert to just test out the result but it's not even returning anything.

```
for(itemSet in fielditems){
    var itemSetValues = fielditems[itemSet];
    for(set in itemSetValues){
        var itemValue = itemSetValues[set];
        for(value in itemvalue){
            alert(itemValue[value]);
        }
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `for()` with `in` for arrays. It's for object properties. Use the standard format instead.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/EVWch/

#### Script:

```js
var fielditems =[
        [["News Tips"],["Opinions"],["MedMinutes"]],
        [["Yes"],["No"],["Maybe"]],
        [["How"],["Why"],["When"]]
    ];

for( var itemIndex = 0; itemIndex < fielditems.length; itemIndex++ ){
    var itemSetValues = fielditems[itemIndex];
    for(var setIndex = 0; setIndex < itemSetValues.length; setIndex++ ){
        var itemValue = itemSetValues[setIndex];
        for(var valueIndex = 0; valueIndex < itemValue.length; valueIndex++ ){
            alert(itemValue[valueIndex]);
        };
    };
};
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, console is your friend. You get error `ReferenceError: itemvalue is not defined` because javascript is case sensitive. Change `itemvalue` in the most nested loop to `itemValue`.

Secondly, if you want iterate thorugh an array, you should use for-loop instead for-in-loop

Answer (score 0):

- Don't use `for-in` loops on arrays
- Don't use (running) variables without declaring them as local

```
for (var i=0; i<fielditems.length; i++) {
    var itemSetValues = fielditems[i];
    for (var j=0; j<itemSetValues.length; j++) {
        var itemvalue = itemSetValues[j]; // notice the case
        for (var k=0; k<itemvalue.length; k++) {
            alert(itemvalue[k]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`for..in` is for objects (`{}`), not for arrays (`[]`).

You need to use a standard `for` loop.

```
for(var i = 0, iLen = fielditems.length; i < iLen; i++){
    var iItem = fielditems[i];
    for(var j = 0, jLen = iItem.length; j < jLen; j++){
        var jItem = iItem[j];
        alert(jItem[0]); // you can also add another loop here, if this will have more elements
    }
}
```

NOTE:

```
for(var i = 0, iLen = fielditems.length; i < iLen; i++)
```

is better than:

```
for(var i = 0; i < fielditems.length; i++)
```

because `fielditems.length` isn't requested each loop, just once at the start.

Comment: I never knew you could do it the way you did it. THANKS!